# How can I avoid transition delays when switching hover between siblings?

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions

How can I avoid transition delays when switching hover between siblings **without javascript**?

My goal is to produce a mega menu with the following behavior:

1. If the user hovers over a given mega menu for 1.5 seconds, the menu will open.
2. If the user moves the mouse away from the mega menu entirely, the mega menu closes instantly.
3. If the user moves the mouse from one mega menu item to another, the second menu replaces the first menu.

My current variation, shown below, has the following behavior (difference is bold):

1. If the user hovers over a given mega menu for 1.5 seconds, the menu will open.
2. If the user moves the mouse away from the mega menu entirely, the mega menu closes instantly.
3. If the user moves the mouse from one mega menu item to another, **the first menu remains open for 1.5 seconds.  Then,** the second menu replaces the first menu.

It also has positioning glitches, but I'm ignoring those for now; this is just a prototype.

This is easily accomplished with javascript, but my goal is to do so purely using CSS3.

```css
.power > div {
    display:inline-block;height:25px;background-color:lightblue;
    padding:0;margin:0
}

.hider {
  position:absolute;top:-999px;
  width:80%;
  background-color:pink;
}

.power div:hover .hider {
  top:25px;
  left:0px;
  transition: all 0s 1.5s;
}

.power:hover div .hider{
  background-color:orange;
  transition: all 0s 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="power">
  <div class="one">Menu-One
    <div class="hider"><br/></br/>One</div>
  </div>
  <div class="two">Menu-Two
    <div class="hider"><br/></br/>Two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by for example using `opacity`, like this, where you have a delay on the opacity (affects all) and an individual re-positioning for each sub menu (with no transition)

```css
.power > div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
.hider {
  position: absolute;
  top: -999px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: pink;
}
.power div:hover .hider {
  left: 0px;
  top: 25px;
}
.power:hover div .hider {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: orange;
  transition: opacity 0s 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="power">
  <div class="one">Menu-One
    <div class="hider">
      <br/>
      <br/>One
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="two">Menu-Two
    <div class="hider">
      <br/>
      <br/>Two
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Clever, but at t=0, your implementation is invisibly covering any components that happen to be under it.  E.g., try mousing over a menu on https://jsfiddle.net/zjhrj0L5/1/ and immediately clicking "Click me." I think https://jsfiddle.net/r6ub7rya/ fixes it by using left and top independently for the different mouseovers, but I wonder if there's a reason everyone always sets top AND left when using menu voodoo.

Comment: @Brian Thanks :) ... when it comes to components that might be hidden beneath, let me know if, and I might be able to give you a hint or two. Most of the time one solve that best with making sure that those elements have a `position` other than the default `static`, and when that doesn't work, `z-index` can be a handy fallback.

Comment: Thanks, using left vs top instead of opaque vs left/top works fine.  Basically, one x/y coordinate is set instantly on mouseover of a single menu item and the other x/y coordinate is set after 1.5 seconds of mousing over the entire menu.  Pretty much the same trick you used.